# convert CDO.Message object to string using asp classic

Tags: c#, asp.net, vb.net, cdo.message

i have following CDO.Message object.

```
dim myMail:set myMail= CreateObject("CDO.Message")
myMail.Subject="testSubject"
myMail.From="test@test.com"
myMail.to="test@test.com"
myMail.TextBody="testBody"
```

i want to convert this object to string. as done in following asp.net function

```
public static string ConvertCDOtoString(CDO.Message CDOMsg)
{
    string strMessage = "";

    //Convert CDO Message to ADO Stream
    ADODB.Stream objADO = null;
    objADO = CDOMsg.GetStream();
    objADO.Type = ADODB.StreamTypeEnum.adTypeBinary;
    //Convert ADO Stream to String
    strMessage = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetString((byte[])objADO.Read());
    objADO = null;
    return strMessage;
}
```

i want to do the same in asp classic. can some one help Please

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Got the solution.

```
dim myMail:set myMail= CreateObject("CDO.Message")
myMail.Subject="test subject"
myMail.to="test@test.com"
myMail.TextBody="testing Body message "
myMail.From="test2@test.com"

Dim Stream      
Set Stream = myMail.GetStream()    
'read the encoded data As a string
messageString = Stream.ReadText
```